# Accessing objects from many to many join table - RAILS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

In ActiveRecord/Ruby on Rails if i have a many-to-many relationship set up like so:

```
class Blog < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tagged_blogposts;
  has_many :tags, through: :tagged_blogposts;
end

class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tagged_blogposts
  has_many :blogs, through: :tagged_blogposts
end

class TaggedBlogpost < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :blog
  belongs_to :tag
end
```

How do I select all the Blogs with a given tag_id  ?

So far I have:
TaggedBlogposts.all.where("tag_id=?", "1"), which returns:

```
+----+---------+--------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| id | blog_id | tag_id | created_at              | updated_at              |
+----+---------+--------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| 2  | 1       | 1      | 2015-08-24 03:05:15 UTC | 2015-08-24 03:05:15 UTC |
| 4  | 2       | 1      | 2015-08-24 03:05:15 UTC | 2015-08-24 03:05:15 UTC |
| 7  | 3       | 1      | 2015-08-24 03:05:15 UTC | 2015-08-24 03:05:15 UTC |
| 15 | 6       | 1      | 2015-08-24 03:05:15 UTC | 2015-08-24 03:05:15 UTC |
| 17 | 7       | 1      | 2015-08-24 03:05:15 UTC | 2015-08-24 03:05:15 UTC |
| 24 | 9       | 1      | 2015-08-24 03:05:15 UTC | 2015-08-24 03:05:15 UTC |
| 33 | 13      | 1      | 2015-08-24 03:05:15 UTC | 2015-08-24 03:05:15 UTC |
| 36 | 15      | 1      | 2015-08-24 03:05:15 UTC | 2015-08-24 03:05:15 UTC |
| 46 | 18      | 1      | 2015-08-24 03:05:15 UTC | 2015-08-24 03:05:15 UTC |
| 47 | 19      | 1      | 2015-08-24 03:05:15 UTC | 2015-08-24 03:05:15 UTC |
+----+---------+--------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
```

But from this join table, I want to return the corresponding blog objects. Something like:

```
Blog.all.where(tag_id:1, through: TaggedBlogposts)
```

EDIT: Figured it out:

```
@blogs = Blog.joins(:tags).where("tags.id=?", "#{params[:tagid]}")
```

Answer (score 2):

This should give you the expected Blogs:

```
Blog.joins('tagged_blogposts').where('tagged_blogposts.tag_id = ?', tag_id)
```

Comment: `tagged_blog_posts` should be `tagged_blogposts`

Comment: Thanks - I just edited my q with another answer that works (basically the same thing just joined with the tags table). That is, I assume there is no difference in using either table - correct ?

Comment: Yeah, same thing. That query and my query should give same result.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code

```
Blog.inlcudes(:tagged_blogposts).where('tagged_blogposts.tag_id = ?', 1).references(:tagged_blogposts)
```

Answer (score 0):

First find tag record:
tag = Tag.find tag_id
and then you can get all blogs for this tag using:
tag.blogs